# How to avoid syntax overhead for def definition with pattern matching in Scala?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

How to avoid to wrap args when implementing a def with pattern matching ?

Examples  :

```
def myDef(a: A, b:B, c: C): D = (a,c,d) match {
  case ('qsdqsd, _ , _ ) => ???
  case _ => ???
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can take the tuple as the function argument instead:

```
def myDef(abc: (A,B,C)): D = abc match {
  case ('qxpf, _, _) => ???
  case _ => ???
}
```

Users will have their non-tuple argument lists automatically promoted into tuples.  Observe:

```
scala> def q(ab: (Int,String)) = ab.swap
q: (ab: (Int, String))(String, Int)

scala> q(5,"Fish")
res1: (String, Int) = (Fish,5)
```

Answer (score 4):

You could declare it as a `PartialFunction` so that you could use the `case`-block directly.  This works because a block of `case`s *is* a PartialFunction in Scala.

```
val myDef: PartialFunction[(A, B, C), D] = {
  case ("qsdqsd", b, c) => b + c
  case _ => "no match"
}

println(myDef("qsdqsd", "b", "c"))
println(myDef("a", "b", "c"))
```

Comment: +1; doesn't work with generic types, but solves the stated problem well!